# Load 8000px png drawable Android Scrollable Image

Tags: android, image, kotlin, memory, scroll

I am really trying to figure out which is the best way of loading a huge image in Android ImageView( or some other view extending ImageView).

I am aware of OOM issues with Android framework when working with bitmaps but still I need to implement the following requests:

- horizontal scrollable imageview
- must load a huge 8000px (keeping original image quality so no downsample) width and device height png image from drawble-nodpi in it and to be fluent while scrolling it without preloads or lag(recyclerview will have blinks so it is a no go I tried that)
- I am thinking at a customview extending imageview and something to decode only current scrolled region from that bitmap but I am stuck here
- avoid oom
- also does a pdf viewer library be better than using huge png from performance point of view? I need the picture preloaded on app start not lazy loaded

Comment: https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare! unortunately i can't find a way to preload that picture in SubsamplingImageView it appears with delay and i need it to be ready when that activity starts. Tested with an image of 8000-750px